# Using blender from a remote machine

Tags: python

I used to stream blender via Steam or TeamViewer, until recently. I tried to use it, and it only showed blank screen. I tried turning hardware encoding on and off, didn't solve anything.

Is there anyone who is pulling this off ? If so, how ? Or anyone knows what might be the problem ?

(Windows 10 on both machines, main righ - Amd ryzen 5 2600, gtx 1070, 16 gb ram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, TeamViewer.

I have installed some monitor driver because of it (which also prevented me from changing brightness of my monitor), after realizing this, I changed back, and the Blender worked ever after.

That's it, TeamViewer.